# Unity2D Register which player colliders have activated

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, jumping

I have a player character that has three separate coliders that form this shape (one for the top, one for the bottom, and one for both sides) [image]

I'm trying to register floor collisions with the bottom collider so that I can reset jumping stuff (double jumps, etc), but since the corners are all touching the floor, I end up having the side colliders enter as well when I use `OnCollisionEnter2D()`.

Is there a way to get which colliders are contacting, or is there a better way to register these collisions?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a single rectangle only? Calculate the distance to the other colliding asset.

The smaller component will tell you the axis, the sign of that component the direction.

For example a positive x could indicate a collision on the right, while a negative value wouldn't indicate a collision from the left.